# CRON JOB ERROR /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory

Tags: node.js, shell, cron

i was getting this error in cron job

```
 /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

so i did this

```
 */10 * * * * . $HOME/.bashrc sh /path/to/cronjob.sh
```

in my cron job

but then it gives me this error

```
 /etc/cron.daily/man-db:
 /usr/bin/mandb: can't set the locale; make sure $LC_* and $LANG are correct
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are doing this directly in the cron entry:
`. $HOME/.bashrc` you are actually asking the user cron to set its environment and most likely it has no Locale defined.

You should set your environment in your script directly just after setting the bash directive:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    . $HOME/.bashrc
    echo Hello World
```

It would be better if you configure `.bash_profile` to load `.profile` and then load `.bashrc`

Comment: thanks for the replay .. how can i configure .bas_profile to .profile

Comment: it is still giving me same error /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory .. i tried writing this lines within the script

Comment: or is this because i am using a amazon EC2 instances of DEBIAN 6.0.1

Comment: @user310685 Did you installed nodejs using a package manager ( apt-get or yum ) ? If so, than maybe your package is called nodejs not node and you should add a symlink from it to your `/usr/bin/node` like this:        
`ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

Comment: Thanks for the comment .. firstly i tried ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node it was not working but then i found my env was corrupted so i reinstalled the debain and did ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node then it worked for me thanks for the replay